# How to overrite schema method from CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

CakePHP has some functions to map a table, I've found TableSchema. I want to overite the function schema(). I want to return dinamically the columns like:

```
$model = $this->loadModel($this->request->controller);
$schema = $model->schema();
```

but this `->schema()` return protected. How can I create a class to modify this behaviour to return public variables from CakePHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like: ->getSchema() to get all the schema as public, another way is to use ->typeMap() this will send you the columns and data types, for each column.